# Problem with "begin proof"

Tags: theorems, languages

I have this question, When i write

\begin{proof}

\end{proof}

In the PDF file it gives "Démonstration" in french, and i want that it gives "Proof" !!

Is there a solution of this problem, thank you !

This is my code:

```
 \documentclass{these}
    
    
    \usepackage{lmodern}
    \usepackage[all]{xy}
    \usepackage{amsmath}
    \usepackage{amsfonts}
    \usepackage{amssymb}
    \usepackage{enumerate}
    \usepackage{amsthm}
    \usepackage{multirow}
    \usepackage{graphicx}
    \usepackage{epsfig}
    \usepackage{fancybox}
    \usepackage{moreverb}
    \usepackage{textcomp}
    \usepackage{pifont}
    \usepackage{float}
    \usepackage{mdframed}
    
    \usepackage{hyperref}
    \hypersetup{colorlinks=true,linkcolor=red,urlcolor=blue}
    
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} %spécification de l'encodage du fichier .tex, à
                                %changer si c'est du latin1
    \usepackage[english,french]{babel}
    \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}


\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}[section]
\newtheorem{lemma}[definition]{Lemma}
\newtheorem{sublemma}[definition]{Sublemma}
\newtheorem{corollary}[definition]{Corollary}
\newtheorem{proposition}[definition]{Proposition}
\newtheorem{theorem}[definition]{Theorem}
\newtheorem{fact}[definition]{Fact}
\newtheorem{question}[definition]{Question}
\newtheorem{remark}[definition]{Remark}
\newtheorem{example}[definition]{Example}
\newtheorem{assumption}[definition]{Assumption}
\newtheorem{conjecture}[definition]{Conjecture}
\newmdtheoremenv{theo}{Théorème}


\newcommand{\cov}{\mathrm{covol}}
\def \tr{{\mathrm{tr}}}
\def \det{{\mathrm{det}\;}}
\def\co{\colon\tanhinspace}
\def\I{{\mathcal I}}
\def\N{{\mathbb N}}
\def\R{{\mathbb R}}
\def\Z{{\mathbb Z}}
\def\Sph{{\mathbb S}}
\def\Tor{{\mathbb T}}
\def\Disk{{\mathbb D}}
\def\Hess{\mathrm{Hess}}
\def\rad{\mathbf{v}}

\def\H{{\mathbb H}}
\def\RP{{\mathbb R}{\mathrm{P}}}
\def\dS{{\mathrm d}{\mathbb{S}}}
\def\Isom{\mathrm{Isom}}

\def\pr{\mathrm{pr}}

\def\sh{\mathrm{sinh}\,}
\def\ch{\mathrm{cosh}\,}
\newcommand{\arccosh}{\mathop{\mathrm{arccosh}}\nolimits}
\newcommand{\oh}{\overline{h}}

\newcommand{\mf}{\mathfrak}
\newcommand{\mb}{\mathbb}
\newcommand{\ol}{\overline}
\newcommand{\la}{\langle}
\newcommand{\ra}{\rangle}
\newcommand{\hess}{\mathrm{Hess}\;}
\newcommand{\grad}{\mathrm{grad}}
\newcommand{\M}{\mathrm{MA}}
\newcommand{\II}{\textsc{I\hspace{-0.05 cm}I}}
\renewcommand{\d}{\mathrm{d}}
\newcommand{\A}{\mathrm{A}}
\renewcommand{\L}{\mathcal{L}}
\newcommand{\FB}[1]{{\color{red}#1}}
\newcommand{\note}[1]{{\color{blue}{\small #1}}}
\newcommand{\Area}{\mathrm{Area}}

\def\blankpage{%
      \clearpage%
      \thispagestyle{empty}%
      \addtocounter{page}{-1}%
      \null%
      \clearpage}


\newcommand\blfootnote[1]{%
  \begingroup
  \renewcommand\thefootnote{}\footnote{#1}%
  \addtocounter{footnote}{-1}%
  \endgroup
}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\thesection{\thechapter.\@arabic\c@section}
\makeatother
```

Comment: Please, what is your complete code that you can add?

Comment: It's quite likely that you have `\usepackage[french]{babel}`. If your document is in English, remove that call. If your document is in French, then you *do* want “Démonstration”, don't you?

Comment: edited......... iwant that it gives "Proof" and not "Démonstration"

Comment: @egreg The introduction of my thesis is in french and the rest is in english !!

Comment: Reverse `french` and `english`; then use `\selectlanguage{french}` before the French introduction and `\selectlanguage{english}` after it.

Comment: And avoid `\def` and `\renewcommand`. You're redefining several commands that can give you strange problems. If you cite a paper by Erdős, you'll know what I mean.

Comment: It works by reversing  french and english; thank you very much !!

Comment: I voted to `close` this post, as it was solved via `comments`

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is solved in the comments.